# How much music listening is harmless using earphones?

Tags: hearing, ear

With Smart phones, we can always be connected and can consume media both Audio and video, almost all day without any interruption.

Generally, when people listen to music, its always with earphones plugged-into ears. A common use case is when commuting we always listen to music with earphones.

**My Question is**: How much music one should listen with plugged-in earphones in a day, without causing ear/organ damage? Looking for a general medical advice here for healthy ear functioning yet consuming favorite music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should not listen to music at 85 decibels for more than 8 hours. And if it's at 88 decibels limit your time to 4 hours.**

To judge this you have to use [decibels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel):

[Livescience.com](http://www.livescience.com/32783-how-loud-can-you-play-music-without-damaging-your-hearing.html)

- > A person exposed to noise levels at 85 decibels or higher for a
  >   prolonged period of time is at risk for hearing loss
- > You shouldn't listen to music , or be exposed to any noise, at 85
  >   decibels for more than 8 hours at a time, said Gordon Hughes, program
  >   officer of clinical trials at the National Institute on Deafness and
  >   Other Communication Disorders (NIDCD). If you've got the volume
  >   cranked to 88 decibels, then cut your listening time down to 4 hours.
- > At its loudest, an MP3 player pumps out 105 decibels that's100 times
  >   more intense than 85 decibels
- > "One way you can tell if your music is too loud is if you're talking
  >   to a friend and you have to raise your voice to be heard," Hughes
  >   said. Normal conversation is around 60 decibels

Articles that agree with the above:

- [Personal music players and hearing loss: Are we deaf to the risks?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3205831/)
- [Ear Infection and Hearing Loss Amongst Headphone Users](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3406203/)

You can find how may decibels your listening at by going online or looking at your manual for your device. This is more acurate as all devices are different. If that doesnt tell you there are [apps and other devices.](http://m.wikihow.com/Measure-Decibels)

Comment: Interesting!! But for a avg. user, not sure how to determine at what decibel he/she is hearing the music. I guess the take away here is that you should not hear the music too loud for more than 6-8 Hours in a day, if I understood your answer correctly.

Comment: @AADTechnical I added what you could use for that. There are apps and it might be in your phone manual or online.

Comment: A person speaking is about 60dB. So it's easy: if you can still normally understand someone talking to you, you're far from the limits. Source: I listen to headphones all day too, and checked it with a dB meter.

Comment: @FrankKusters accurately checking the sound level of headphones with a "dB meter" is non trivial are requires a coupler that matches the acoustic impedance of the ear.

Comment: @StrongBad That's what [filters on the dB meter](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/decibel-d_59.html) are for.